# Keeping a pointer to another class

Tags: c++

I want to keep a pointer (or a reference) to another class. It could be a class which contains a matrix of pointers to a base class, and I want to be able to use public functions of that class inside a function of a class that has a pointer (or reference) to it. Let's say it looks something like this:

base.h

```
#pragma once

class base
{
protected:
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    void setX (int _x)
    {
        x=_x;
    }
    void setY (int _y)
    {
        y=_y;
    }
    virtual void f ()=0;
};
```

derived.h

```
#pragma once
#include "base.h"
#include "container.h"

class derived : public base
{
private:
    container* c;
public:
    derived (container* c, int x, int y)
        : c(c)
    {
        setX(x);
        setY(y);
    }

    void g ()
    {
        c->doStuff();
    }

    virtual void f ()
    {
        std::cout<<"f"<<std::endl;
    }
};
```

container.h

```
 #pragma once
 #include "base.h"
 #include "derived.h"

 class container
 {
 private:
    base*** mat;
 public:
    container ()
    {
        mat=new base**[10];
        for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
            mat[i]=new base*[10];

        for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
            for (int j=0; j<10; ++i)
                mat[i][j]=NULL;

        mat[5][5]=new derived(this, 1, 2);
     }

    void doStuff ()
    {
        std::cout<<"stuff"<<std::endl;
    }
 };
```

I keep getting these errors

```
derived.h(8): error     C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
derived.h(8): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
derived.h(10): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'container'
derived.h(10): error C2065: 'c' : undeclared identifier
derived.h(12): error C2614: 'derived' : illegal member initialization: 'c' is not a base or member
derived.h(19): error C2065: 'c' : undeclared identifier
derived.h(19): error C2227: left of '->doStuff' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
1>          type is ''unknown-type''
container.h(20): error C2661: 'derived::derived' : no overloaded function takes 3 arguments
```

I know I'm missing something and I just can't pinpoint what it is

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a cyclic include dependency between `container.h` and `derived.h`. Fortunately, it can be avoided, since `derived` does not need the full definition of `container`, so you can use a forward declaration instead of an include:

```
#ifndef DERIVED_H_
#define DERIVED_H_
#include "base.h"

class container; // fwd declaration

class derived : public base
{
private:
    container* c;

//... as before

#endif
```

You will need to `#include "container.h"` in the implementation of `derived`.

As a general rule, you should include everything that needs to be included, and nothing more.

Comment: I'd like to note that using forward declarations is a good practice, not only while getting rid of cyclic dependencies. Redundant `#include`s should be avoided always when it is possible.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you. I couldn't make it work if implementation was in .h as well. Yet another reason to have separate .h and .cpp files but I was too lazy for that.